# Loop Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

how to loop an array if the data is 1 or more than 1?

[image]

I tried it with

```
foreach($array['bGeneral'] as $item) {
    echo $item['bItem'];
}
```

but for arrays that have 1 data an error

Comment: You could write a loop in a loop.

Comment: Please add an example array in code. Also, what is is the error that is appearing for 1 entry?

Comment: In the screenshot there is no `bDate` is that correct?

Comment: sorry I wrote wrong, bDate should be bItem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to check if the first element of `$array['bGeneral']` is an array or a data value, and if so, process the data differently. You could try something like this:

```
if (isset($array['bGeneral']['bItem'])) {
    // only one set of values
    $item = $array['bGeneral'];
    // process item
}
else {
    // array of items
    foreach ($array['bGeneral'] as $item) {
        // process item
    }
}
```

To avoid duplication of code, you will probably want to put the item processing code in a function.

Alternatively you could create a multi-dimensional array when you only have one value and then continue processing as you do with multiple values:

```
if (isset($array['bGeneral']['bItem'])) {
    $array['bGeneral'] = array($array['bGeneral']);
}
foreach ($array['bGeneral'] as $item) {
    // process item
}
```

Comment: No worries - sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes to look at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget recursion - sometimes it is a best choise :

```
function scan_data($data, $path = null) {
    if (!is_array($data))
        echo "{$path} : {$data}\n";
    else
        foreach ($data as $k => $v)
            scan_data($v, $path . '/' . $k);
}

$data = [
    ['a' => 1,                    'b' => 2], 
    ['a' => ['c' => 3, 'd' => 4], 'b' => 5],
    ['a' => 1,                    'b' => ['e' => ['f' => 1, 'g' => 2], 'h' => 6] ]
   ];

scan_data($data);
```

Output:

> /0/a : 1
>   
> /0/b : 2
>   
> /1/a/c : 3
>   
> /1/a/d : 4
>   
> /1/b : 5
>   
> /2/a : 1
>   
> /2/b/e/f : 1
>   
> /2/b/e/g : 2
>   
> /2/b/h : 6